# R does not warn and reads only some data from a txt file

Tags: r, csv, text-files

I am clueless on whats happening. I am trying to read a utf-8 txt file in R. The values are separated by tabs. Following is an excerpt from the file:

```
   LOCATION       FORM  TAG  FEATURES
1 (1:1:1:1)         bi   P   PREFIX|bi+
2 (1:1:1:2)       somi   N   STEM|POS:N|LEM:{som|ROOT:smw|M|GEN
3 (1:1:2:1)    {ll~ahi  PN   STEM|POS:PN|LEM:{ll~ah|ROOT:Alh|GEN
4 (1:1:3:1)         {l DET   PREFIX|Al+
5 (1:1:3:2) r~aHoma`ni ADJ   STEM|POS:ADJ|LEM:r~aHoma`n|ROOT:rHm|MS|GEN
6 (1:1:4:1)         {l DET   PREFIX|Al+
```

The file can be downloaded from [Quranic Arabic Corpus Downloads](http://corpus.quran.com/download/)

Here is one of the ways I tried reading the file:

```
test <- read.csv(file = "quranic-corpus-morphology-0.4.txt",
                 sep = "\t", header = TRUE, skip = 56, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The problem is the number of records being read. I can easily see the difference in record count. `read.csv` returns 77109 records, without any warning. Whereas opening the same file in LibreOffice Calc, I see the 128219 records.

Reading the file via `read.table`:

```
test <- read.table(file = "quranic-corpus-morphology-0.4.txt", 
               sep = "\t", header = TRUE, 
               skip = 56, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

returns

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     line 78 did not have 4 elements

And I could not figure out whats wrong with line 78.

To get clean csv I have even tried, save as csv from LibreOffice Calc, which return this warning

> This document may contain formatting or content that cannot be saved in the currently selected file format “Text CSV”.

**lines 135-140:**

```
(2:7:4:1)   quluwbi N       STEM|POS:N|LEM:qalob|ROOT:qlb|FP|GEN
(2:7:4:2)   himo    PRON    SUFFIX|PRON:3MP
(2:7:5:1)   wa      CONJ    PREFIX|w:CONJ+
(2:7:5:2)   EalaY`  P       STEM|POS:P|LEM:EalaY`
(2:7:6:1)   samoEi  N       STEM|POS:N|LEM:samoE|ROOT:smE|M|GEN
(2:7:6:2)   himo    PRON    SUFFIX|PRON:3MP
```

Comment: Can you include line 78 in your question?  The error seems to be saying that R did not find 4 columns, i.e. it found less or more than 4 columns.

Comment: I am skipping first 56 lines having copyright text, so 78 would be relative, which row number should i include ?

Comment: Please include 135-140 if possible.  But first check to make sure the data from these lines even makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell R to treat quotes in your data as any other character or else it's gonna treat the rest of it as a string until end-quote,

line 62 (after skipping 56 lines) seems to have `'` in the 4th column `STEM|POS:V|IMPF|(IV)|LEM:'aAmana|ROOT:Amn|3MP`.

Try :

```
test <- read.csv(file = "quranic-corpus-morphology-0.4.txt",
                 sep = "\t", header = TRUE, skip = 56, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote="")
```

Output :

```
> str(test)
'data.frame':   128219 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ LOCATION: chr  "(1:1:1:1)" "(1:1:1:2)" "(1:1:2:1)" "(1:1:3:1)" ...
 $ FORM    : chr  "bi" "somi" "{ll~ahi" "{l" ...
 $ TAG     : chr  "P" "N" "PN" "DET" ...
 $ FEATURES: chr  "PREFIX|bi+" "STEM|POS:N|LEM:{som|ROOT:smw|M|GEN" "STEM|POS:PN|LEM:{ll~ah|ROOT:Alh|GEN" "PREFIX|Al+" ...
```